# How often keepSynced() checks for new nodes?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to wrap my head around Firebase's offline capability's method `keepSynced(true)`. In my app I want to make sure I have an updated local cache of a certain part of my database so I've added the following lines:

```
let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(user.uid).child("pets")
userRef.keepSynced(true)

// Here I do things with the ref's values expecting it to have the latest values
userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    ...
```

I've also added `FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true` in my `AppDelegate.swift`

Does `keepSynced()` behave like an onChange listener so when a node is changed/added/removed upstream it atomically receives an updated version of its tracked ref's value or does it do a query at specific intervals of time?

Comment: You should be able to observe the result of setting `keepSynced(true)` by enabling debug logging with [setLoggingEnabled()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabase#setloggingenabled) and using the Firebase console to make test changes to your data.  I expect you'll see that changes are detected immediately--like having an active listener.  That's what I see on Android.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Bob. I'd suspect it's the same on iOS then.